# Why do chaotic numbers improve evolutionary algorithms such as genetic algorithm?

Tags: chaos-theory, randomness

I have implemented a genetic algorithm to solve a problem. In the process of genetic algorithm, instead of random numbers, I have used the chaotic numbers generated by the logistics map. The genetic algorithm that uses chaotic numbers is more efficient than the genetic algorithm that uses random numbers. Why the use of chaotic numbers improves the efficiency of the genetic algorithm?

Comment: how are your random numbers generated? You may know that random numbers generated by computers are usually not truly "random"...what is the algorithm that you use to obtain the random numbers?

Comment: I generate random numbers using uniform distribution like "rand" function in MATLAB

Comment: The "random" numbers generated by Matlab are pseudorandom, in the sense that they are generated by a deterministic algorithm. But maybe this is not the reason why you get different results. I think the main difference is that the chaotic numbers are not uniformly distributed. So, you generate random numbers with uniform distribution in a fixed interval?  Have you tried to use random numbers with another probability distribution?

Comment: In the evolutionary algorithm, random numbers with uniform distribution are used to select parents and variation operators. I have implemented the genetic algorithm twice: 1) Using MATLAB "rand" function to generate uniform random numbers to select parents and variation operators, and 2) Using "Logistic map" to generate chaotic numbers to select parents and variation operators. This is the only difference in two implementations.

Comment: I understood this. The "chaotic" numbers are not uniformly distributed. You may try to use other probability distributions and see if your results improve. Anyway, are you sure that the rand function gives uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers? or they are normally distributed instead?

Comment: Please define the "efficiency" of the GA. Is it the fitness convergence rate, or something else? An initial guess is that you are getting non-uniform selection of parents that leads to an effective population structure that is helpful, but this may be very problem dependent. So what problems have you run the algorithm on?

Comment: I consider the fitness convergence rate as the efficiency of GA and I uses GA to solve the graph coloring problem.

Answer (score 1):

A number of papers ([1](https://doi.org/10.1088/0253-6102/38/2/168), [2](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13495-1_52), [3](http://www.inase.org/library/2013/rhodes/bypaper/SCSI/SCSI-33.pdf), [4](https://doi.org/10.22260/ISARC2009/0049), [5](https://iajit.org/PDF/vol.12,no.2/6039.pdf)) make the same observation as yours, which is usually [explained as](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2016.01.007) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293646778_A_chaos-based_evolutionary_algorithm_for_general_nonlinear_programming_problems))

> The inherent characteristics of chaos can enhance optimization algorithms by enabling it to escape from local solutions and increase the convergence to reach to the global solution.

It has also [been claimed](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.procs.2015.05.248) that a mix of periodic and chaotic search results in a better search strategy:

> the convergent behavior leads to exploitation and the chaotic behavior aids to exploration.

Another [paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5048299) ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01896)) reported a positive effect of using chaos for generating initial populations only, but not when used as a RNG:

> The use of chaotic maps for the generation of the initial populations in the genetic algorithm, increases consider-ably the performance of the algorithm in comparison to the tradition stochastic algorithm.
> In  addition,  the  proposed  algorithm  was  also  modified using chaotic maps in the mutation and the population processes.  However, the results obtained using these modifications do not show significant improvement.

This same paper also claims to have found a direct link to entropy:

> We found a strong relationship between the entropy of the initial populations and the densities of fitness of the solutions. [...] the chaotic maps with higher entropies show an increase in the fitness’s densities in the areas with better solutions: high entropies generated better solutions.

Comment: Doesn't the uniform distribution have the highest possible entropy? So wouldn't the entropy-based conclusion suggest that a uniformly-distributed initial population should perform better than a non-uniform distribution generated by a chaotic map?

Comment: @probably_someone I had the same thought and honestly still can't understand their claim, even after reading the relevant sections of their paper.